# node_redis updating used memory info

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using the [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) client and I want to monitor the amount of memory that is currently used by Redis:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

setInterval(() => {
  // add much data to redis, then:
  console.log(redisClient.server_info.used_memory);
}, 1000);
```

This logs the same amount of memory per each interval. However, if i use the redis-cli "info" command, I can see the memory increasing.

The only solution I've come up with is to create a new client each time I want to check the memory:

```
const redis = require('redis');

setInterval(() => {
  // add much data to redis, then create new client to watch memory:
  const redisClient = redis.createClient();
  console.log(redisClient.server_info.used_memory);
  redisClient.quit();
}, 1000);
```

This doesn't feel like the right way to do it, though. Is there a way to "update" the used_memory info without creating a new client every time?

Comment: Have you tried calling `redisClient.info()`?

Comment: `redisClient.info()` just returns `true`

Comment: That's an asynchronous call. You use it like other calls, e.g. `redisClient.info(function(err, res) { console.log(res); });`.

Comment: ah, yeah I saw that in the source code of node_redis now. However, `res` is just a huge string containing the same information that the redis-cli "info" command does. Not sure how I would access the value of "used_memory" from that string. I could try regex...

Comment: Well, you have to parse it :)

Comment: @Junker could you verify the answer and mark it as accepted if it works? otherwise leave a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
setInterval(() => {
  redisClient.info((req, res) => {
    res.split("\n").map((line) => {
      if (line.match(/used_memory_human/)) {
        console.log('Used memory: ' + line.split(":")[1]);
      }
    })
  });
}, 1000);
```

It will split the output of your `info` output by line, and print the value of the line containing `used_memory_human`

Answer (score 1):

Mihai's answer works, but I will caution the value of `line.split(":")[1]` has a hidden `\r` at the end of the string. When used at the end of a console statement this won't be a problem, but you'll need to remove the `\r` if you want to use the value in the middle of a log statement, otherwise the resulting console.log will be garbled.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much cleaner answer to Mihai's one and probably the best one to use in a production environment.

```
setInterval(() => {
    redisClient.info((err, info) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        
        const used = info.split("\n").find(line => line.match(/used_memory_human/)).split(":")[1];

        console.log("Used Memory:", used);
    });
}, 1000);
```